# How to express diacritics in RegEx?

Tags: .net, regex, diacritics

I was wondering what a regular expression that allows diacritic characters look like in .NET. Is there a shorthand for all the diacritic characters?

Comment: *Only*  diacritics (like `´`)?  Or only letters with diacritics (like `é`)? Or letters with or without diacritics (like `e` or `é`)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I am referring to letters with accents over them, but I don't mind knowing about diacritics without the accents.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this(As suggested by Tim in comments):-

```
^\p{L}*$
```

Also check out [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html).